# Can`t get json object to with knockout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery, knockout.js

I can`t get json object.

My object is:

```
public class Person
{
   public string firstName { get; set; }
   public string lastName { get; set; }        
}
```

PersonsControll:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // GET: /Persons/GetPerson
    //[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    //[OutputCache(Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]
    public JsonResult GetPerson()
    {
        Person p = new Person { firstName = "Jonas", lastName = "Antanaitis" };
        return Json(p, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

My  index view:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/knockout")

<p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
<p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>

<div id="dispJson"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">                
    var data = $.getJSON(".../GetPerson", function (result) {
        //state = result.readyState;
        firstName: result.firsName;
        lastName: result.lastName;
    })    
    .error(function () { alert("error"); });    

    function viewModel() {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data);
        //state = data.readyState;
        //firstName = data.firstName;
        //lastName = data.lastName;
    };    
    document.write(JSON.stringify(data)); //this line prints  "{"readyState":1}"

    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());    
</script>
```

When I go to ".../GetPerson" in browser, I get this displayed:
**{"firstName":"Jonas","lastName":"Antanaitis"}**

,but when try to get data witch javascript in view - I dont`t get this data.

**What I am doing wrong, why I cant get data?**
Where commented code - I tried this approaches.. but nothing helped.

I tried:

```
*$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache: false,
    url: ".../GetPerson",        
}).done(function (msg) {
    alert("Data Saved: " + msg.readyState + "  " + msg.firstName + "  " + msg.lastName);
});*
```

Then alert box displays: "*Data Saved: undefined  Jonas  Antanaitis*"

Comment: Can you check the network tab in the browser debugger tool to check the url it is trying to reach when you use the ajax call. The ajax url `.../GetPerson` looks a little off. Using the `Url` helper similar to: `@Url.Action("GetPerson", "Persons")` to generate the url might work better in your JSON or Ajax call.

Comment: My original URL = "h t t p://localhost:52368/Persons/GetPerson"   (I writed shorty becouse, I cant post full url). In network shows two requests: "h t t p://localhost:52368/Persons/GetPerson?_=1359611346968"   and "h t t p://localhost:52368/Persons/GetPerson"

Comment: ah. I see. In that case if the urls are the same it's probably related to `felix`'s answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing async code with sync code... You have this line here

```
var data = $.getJSON(".../GetPerson", function (result) {
```

`data` will actually be the a promise (this is what the ajax returns). You do not actually have the data until the callback executes - ie result is the thing that has the ACTUAL data.

You need to move the binding to INSIDE the callback OR use an observable that you set after the fact:

1) Inside the callback example

```
<script type="text/javascript">                
    $.getJSON(".../GetPerson", function (result) {

        function viewModel() {
            return ko.mapping.fromJS(result);
        };

        ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
    })    
    .error(function () { alert("error"); });        
</script>
```

2) Use an observable

```
<script>
    function viewModel() {
        return { data: ko.observable() };
    };

    // Your html bindings will bind to data.* instead of just *
    ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());

    $.getJSON(".../GetPerson", function (result) {
        data(ko.mapping.fromJS(result));
    })    
    .error(function () { alert("error"); });      
</script>
```

And the corresponding html (The with binding makes it a bit cleaner than if):

```
<!-- ko with: data -->
<p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
<p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>
<!-- /ko -->
```

The advantage of the second method is that you are binding everything quickly... and can then show your data as it comes in.

Comment: When I use  {2} approach, in IE returns error: SCRIPT5022: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: 'firstName' is undefined;
Bindings value: text: firstName

Comment: Yup, thats right... in (2) you would have to change to bindings value to: `text: data().firstName` - oh and you would need an `if: data` around it so it wont try to bind if data is null (which it will be initially)

Comment: Maybe you can help with this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636135/how-to-access-and-display-mapped-data-witch-ko-mapping-script-razor-page

Comment: And how to write if?  I tryed {data().firsName, data and so on...}  <div data-bind="if:  data()">    
<strong data-bind="text: data().firstName"></strong>
<strong data-bind="text: data().lastName"></strong>
</div>

Comment: @Felix:  Could you add the if:data and text: data().firstName into your answer, so we can see where they should be?

Comment: @JenniferMichelle sorry - haven't logged in for a while... Changed the answer.