# How to access and display mapped data with ko.mapping script (Razor page)?

Tags: json, knockout.js

Java script (getting data using [Can`t get json object to with knockout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616138/cant-get-json-object-to-with-knockout) answer {1} method):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.getJSON("/api/TelemarketingApi", function (result) {
        function viewModel() {            
            return ko.mapping.fromJS(result);
        };
        ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
    })
    .error(function () { alert("error"); });
</script>
```

JSON object:

```
[
    {
        "TelemCalls": [ {"ID": 1, "duratio": "11"}],
        "ID": 1,
        "FirstName": "Jonas",
        "LastName": "Jonaitis",
        "Phone": "860123123",
        "Municipality": null
    }
]
```

How can I access and display mapped JSON data in a **razor** page?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the viewModel mapped from the json object and binded to entire razor view.
To display values in the razor view only has to create html elements bound to the viewModel like this:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: ID" />
<input type="text" data-bind="value: FirstName" />
<input type="text" data-bind="value: LastName" />
<input type="text" data-bind="value: Phone" />
<input type="text" data-bind="value: Municipality" />
```

Example in Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vfportero/hcVmZ/

Answer (score 0):

Remember that your mapped data is accessible only in JavaScript, not on the server side while page is being built by Razor. So to show viewModel's property values on the page try the following:

```
<input data-bind="value: FirstName" />
<ul data-bind="foreach: TelemCalls">
    <li data-bind="text: duratio"></li>
</ul>
```

If your top-level viewmodel is an array so use the following syntax:

```
<div data-bind="$data">
    <input data-bind="value: FirstName" />
    <ul data-bind="foreach: TelemCalls">
        <li data-bind="text: duratio"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not full answer. Becouse JSON data shown is a list [ ]. and this binding don`t working. (My fault, failed to explain in more detail). But I find out, how (I needed t change mapping line to "return {data:ko.mapping.fromJS(result)};" and I can use foreach data top level variable). [There](http://jsfiddle.net/Drasius/X2c6n/5/) i wrote how to print in details. (Only binding works in my project witch server side, but with java variable for some reason doesn`t work. To morrow I will try to find out)